# Java class.getResourceAsStream does not work for files with leading dot

Tags: java, eclipse, io, maven-3, m2eclipse

Running this Maven project from Eclipse this does not work:

```
MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/package/to/my/resource/" + ".gitignore");
```

But when I rename the `.gitignore` to `gitignore` this works pretty fine:

```
MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/package/to/my/resource/" + "gitignore");
```

The resource files are located under `src/main/resources/package/to/my/resource/`. The `maven-resources-plugin` is not configured in the pom.xml.

The .* files are not moved to target/classes.

Comment: Are you sure the dotfile is actually getting included in your jar?

Comment: Is there a `/` missing in the string concatenation?

Comment: I believe I saw some old Java source where `getResource` which is called by `getResourceAsStream` replaces the last `.` in a string with a `/`.  Not 100% on that but may want to dig into the Java source.

Comment: @sleeplessnerd you were absolutely correct. I corrected the post.

Comment: @chrylis No I'm not, currently I'm running the code from Eclipse.

Comment: @jnbbender That applies to the fully qualified package name only.  No replacement is done on the String argument.

Comment: please provide information how your project is structured. Is it a maven project? - Where is the resource file? In java/main/resources or next to the .java file in the package ? Are you running it within eclipse or are you building a .jar?

Answer (score 3):

Java shouldn't have any problem with "hidden" files. You need to check the output/target folder after building the project. You should find there a `/package/to/my/resource/.gitignore` file. If you cannot find it you should double check Java Build Path in project properties if there is no exclusion for files which begin with a dot.